# CasperJS - Screenshots of table rows

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I'm starting with CasperJS, and I'm interested in the « capture » function. For « exercises », I want to capture each row of a table like this :

```
<table id="idTable">
    <thead>
        <tr id="theader">
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="" rel="xx">
            <td>Content1</td>  
            <td>Content2</td>  
            <td>Content3</td>  
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

So far, I'm here :

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
    clientScripts: ["jquery.min.js"]
});

function createScreenshots() {
    var i = 0;
    $('#idTable > tbody  > tr').each(function() {       
        this.captureSelector('myscreens/'+i+'.png', $(this).selector);
        i++;
    });
}
casper.start('mywebsite.com',function(){
    this.evaluate(createScreenshots);
});
casper.run();
```

But nothing works (no error, but no screenshots in the « myscreens » folder). If someone could show me the way ?

Thanks in advance,

Kai23

Answer (score 0):

`this.captureSelector` is not accessible inside the page context. You need to do the iteration outside the page context.

```
casper.start('mywebsite.com',function(){
    var rows = this.evaluate(function(){
        return document.querySelectorAll("#idTable > tbody  > tr").length;
    });

    for(var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        this.captureSelector('myscreens/'+i+'.png', '#idTable > tbody  > tr:nth-of-type('+i+')');
    }
});
casper.run();
```

Answer (score -1):

What is your jQuery version ?

Have you tried to print $(this).selector

```
$('#idTable > tbody  > tr').each(function() {
  echo $(this).selector;
  i++;
});
```